# Separate a string in SQL in two parts separated by (hyphen) - and store the two parts in a different variable

Tags: sql, database

I need to separate a string in SQL,

Example,

```
a='001A01-001A05'
```

What I need in OUTPUT is,

```
x='001A01'
y='001A05'
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Always 6 plus 6 characters?

Comment: Regardless of mysql or sql server you need to look no further than substring and charindex (sql server) or locate (mysql).

Comment: @jarlh- No, it may vary.

Comment: @VaibhavSinha - You want result in two different rows or columns ? Also will it be always two set like `AAA-BBB` or it can be even `AAA-BBB-CCC`

Comment: I want the result in two different columns and it will always be AAA-BBB. It basically indicates a range. @Prdp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prdp's answer would be my first choice, but if SQL Server 2012+, another option is PARSENAME()

```
Declare @a varchar(25)='001A01-001A05'
Select x=ParseName(Replace(@a,'-','.'),2)
      ,y=ParseName(Replace(@a,'-','.'),1)
```

Returns

```
x       y
001A01  001A05
```

Comment: `PARSENAME` is introduced well before 2012 ;) +1

Comment: @Prdp Funny: Docs still say 2012  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx.  however, I see threads going back to 2003

Comment: That weird I always thought `PARSENAME` is a very old function.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT`, `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`

```
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(500)= '001A01-001A05'

SELECT LEFT(@char, Charindex('-', @char) - 1),
       Substring(@char, Charindex('-', @char) + 1, Len(@char))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this using `LEFT` and `RIGHT`

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)= '001A01-001A05'
select left(@str, charindex('-', @str)-1), 
       right(@str, charindex('-', @str)-1)
```